# How do you say kissing each other's cheeks in spanish?

Tags: saludos, cultura-de-masas

I'm referring to when you greet each other.

Answer (score 6):

> To **kiss** [someone's] cheek

in Spanish is

> **besar** [a alguien] en la mejilla

Among many other meanings, the pronoun **se** can be used to express reciprocity, so "to kiss each other's cheek" would be "besarse en la mejilla" (or "besarse el uno al otro en la mejilla", if the shorter version isn't clear enough, although most people can't kiss their own cheeks so there is no ambiguity here).

Comment: wow, thank you!

Comment: how do you say "to hug each other" or "they often hug each other". Referring to when ur greeting each other.

Comment: Comments aren't for additional questions, but those are "abrazarse" and "a menudo se abrazan", respectively. You could just look it up, though.

Answer (score 6):

I would say something like **se dieron dos besos** - the location of the kisses is understood in most of the contexts -.

I am going to give you [something to read](https://www.lavozdegalicia.es/noticia/yes/2016/02/13/dos-besos-/00031455192297165303579.htm):

> Es llegar a cualquier sitio y, para saludar, **dos besos en la mejilla.**
>   Muac, muac. Siempre igual y con el mismo resultado: impactos de
>   mejilla o de labios en la mejilla, restos de saliva o pintalabios que
>   limpiamos más o menos disimuladamente, picos accidentales por no poner
>   primero la mejilla derecha? ¿Y por qué esa costumbre de dar dos besos
>   para saludar? «Es una cuestión cultural»...
>   *"Dos besos, ¿por qué?" by Alba Precedo (La Voz de Galicia - 13/02/2016)*

It is not a translation page or a dictionary, it is from a newspaper and it uses this expression, so you would read a little bit of the context that it is used

Comment: Es bueno copiar las partes relevantes de los enlaces, pues si se rompen se pierde todo el contenido

Comment: Why two? The kiss can be simultanous.

Comment: @c.p. in my area (north of Spain), greeting women involves two kisses on the cheeks, and we most often call it "darse dos besos", instead of the other expressions that use the word "mejilla(s)". It just has evolved that way there, but it seems to have evolved differently in other areas...

Answer (score 1):

The way I would say it simply is **Saludar de beso en la mejilla (en el cachete)**

Comment: I would say in your case, Saludar CON beso en la mejilla

Comment: @Iria debe ser algo regional, pero en Colombia decimos "saludar DE beso"

Comment: será, dicho así con esa preposición me suena MUY raro, pero si lo decís en Colombia es eso, algo regional